# Do I need to help the ghouls to complete Come Fly With Me?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Do I need to clear the 'demons' from the basement or can I just kill all the ghouls including Jason to satisfy Manny?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Killing Jason, or any other non-feral ghoul at the REPCONN test site will fail Come Fly With Me.

I'm not sure whether this will satisfy Manny however, with respect to finding out where the man who shot you went. If you want to make an end-run around dealing with Repconn however, you can either convince Manny to tell you what he knows by either applying some... 'pressure' via the Confirmed Bachelor perk, or you can just hack the terminal in his room in Novac and read his emails on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will satisfy Manny, you will have to kill all of them. If you don't want to kill all the "demons" there is another option for that too. i.e you don't have to kill anyone except the feral ghouls.

I just did this on my current playthru.